# After Three years I returned to stackexchange to ask one question and get question banned .......:p

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

After three years I returned to stackexchange to ask [one question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369985/2451). Because it was not recieved well, I am now banned from asking with this account. Really? Three years on and there is no room for one honest question?  I have had a few poorly recieved questions in the past but I have also had a few which were very well recieved. Seems to me, this ban is a bit harsh.

Comment: I assume you have deleted the question since I can't see it [in your activity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/33995/user33995?tab=questions). Deleting questions usually makes matters worse. If you undelete it and post the link here we can have a look and see if the question can be salvaged.

Comment: You previous record still exists. Of the 17 questions you've asked, six are negatively voted, six (a intersecting but distinct set) are deleted, and eight (another set which intersect both the others but subsumes neither) are closed for reasons other than duplication. All told a majority of your questions are closed, deleted, or negatively scored.

Comment: I _think_ this is close enough to what's happening in the other question that it qualifies as a duplicate.